# Getter only property in C++/CLI interface

Tags: interface, properties, c++-cli

What is the equivalent C++/CLI syntax to the following C# declaration (if such exists):

```
interface MyInterface
{
    int MyProperty {get;}
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
interface class MyInterface
{
    property int MyProperty 
    {
       int get();
    }
};
```

See example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/e0fc8a65-7ea2-4a8a-b808-e9c1f7871164)